# Finding Which services are running in target windows host based on given service list and start if the service is not running

Tags: ansible, windows-services, system-administration

I have a set of windows services and need to find out whether those services are running in the target windows host. If at least one of the services no running I need to start those services and need to set the start mode to auto.

```yaml
- name: Check weather service is running or not
    ansible.windows.win_service_info:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    register: win_service_info
    with_items:
      - BrokerInfrastructure #Background Tasks Infrastructure (BrokerInfrastructure) Service
      - DcomLaunch #DCOM Server Process Launcher Service
      - gpsvc #Group Policy Client Service
      
  - name: Start the services
    ansible.windows.win_service:
      name: << don't know how to write this part >>
      start_mode: auto
      state: started
    register: service_startup 
    with_items: "{{ win_service_info.results }}"
    when: << don't know how to write this part >>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to find the service state beforehand. Just describe the state in which the service should be, ansible will report `changed` if it had to modify anything (start the service, change the start mode...) or `ok` if it was already in the expected state.

```yaml
  - name: Start/modify the services if needed
    ansible.windows.win_service:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      start_mode: auto
      state: started
    with_items:
      - BrokerInfrastructure 
      - DcomLaunch
      - gpsvc
```

---

Now if you still want to detect the service state prior to doing a specific task, you should simply debug your `win_service_info.results` variable to have a pretty good overview. I cannot test that myself since I don't have any windows box at hand. But if I believe the [`win_service_info` module's returned values documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html#return-values), you can do something like the following:

```yaml
- name: do something depending on service state
  debug:
    msg: "I would do something because service {{ item.services.0.name }}
           is in state {{ item.services.0.state }}"
  when:
    - item.exists
    - item.services.0.state in ['stopped', 'paused']
  loop: "{{ win_service_info }}"
```